# Export EDITOR with a flag

Tags: zsh, editors

I'm using Zsh and some CLI's such as Google's `gcloud` load files via `$EDITOR`.

For me, I have set this as:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mvim"
```

With aliases for that editor using the `-v` flag which loads vim in the terminal:

```
 mac_vim="$EDITOR -v"
 alias vi=$mac_vim
 alias vim=$mac_vim
 alias v=$mac_vim
```

That works but when the `gcloud` CLI calls `$EDITOR` it does not have the `-v` flag so it opens in a new terminal.  I thought I could change that by instead adding the `-v` flag here:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mvim -v"
```

However, when I try and run that on the command line I get:

```
$EDITOR text.html
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/mvim -v
```

Is it possible to include a flag when exporting my `$EDITOR`?

Comment: Wrap it in a script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a wafer-thin shell wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/bin/mvim -v "$@"
```

And stash that somewhere (somewhere in `PATH` or maybe in `~/libexec` or whatever) and then set that wrapper as the `EDITOR` value.

With ZSH, one could force the expansion:

```
% EDITOR='echo -E'
% $EDITOR /etc/passwd
zsh: command not found: echo -E
% $=EDITOR /etc/passwd
/etc/passwd
%
```

As detailed in `zshexpn(1)`:

```
   ${=spec}
          Perform  word splitting using the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during
```

Note that ZSH contradicts other shells on the matter of **not** doing `SH_WORD_SPLIT` by default. The POSIX default, by the way, is a mighty fine rake that many have used incorrectly and thus have stepped on and been whacked by:

```
% DERP="/var /nish"
% ls $DERP
ls: cannot access /var /nish: No such file or directory
% sudo bash
# DERP="/var /nish"
# rm -rf $DERP 
...
```

However various other programs, possibly ones that do not know how to perform shell word splitting, may call `EDITOR`. The most portable option for `EDITOR` is therefor something that can be executed directly by an `exec(3)` call, and if necessary that script can add any flags for the editor actual. Hence, a wafer-thin wrapper.

Comment: That makes sense, I'd like to understand why I can't add the flag as part of the export.  Any explanation on that piece?

Comment: Whether this works depends on how the application in question calls $EDITOR. The simple way is to treat it as a single string pointing to a file, and this is what gcloud apparently does. For flags in the export to work, the application would have to parse the string like a shell does and pass the words as separate arguments in argv.